# Topology of Adhoc Network

Tags: ad-hoc-network

I can connect 3 or 4 laptops (running windows or linux) in adhoc network and each laptop is able to ping other laptop. I am curios about what topology does adhoc network uses. do they connect in mesh topology?. Or does underlying OS provide some multihop routing protocol. Can I change toplogy of this adhoc network?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ad hoc networks are a thing. Each node will be able to communicate with the others. Multiphop (they are multihop) Ad hoc networks dynamically self-reorganize as necessary. Google 'MANET' - Mobile Ad hoc Network.

Ad hoc networks are not MESH networks. MESH networks rely on stationary mesh routers that provide the backbone of the ad hoc network as well as links to the internet and sometimes other segments of the network via routing between geographically separated mesh routers.

You can join multiple laptops regardless of OS to the same ad hoc network.

Comment: Thanks Alex. What protocol adhoc network use for multihop routing when I connect 4 or 5 laptops together. and does this protocol changest from OS to OS (e.g. on Windows and Linux)